# Someone else's (perspective / point of view)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, phrases, collocations

> - Someone can think this is a legal issue that just has to be solved. But it might look different ...................

**a.** from someone else's **point of view**. 
**b.** from the **point of view** of someone else. 
**c.** from someone else's **perspective**. 
**d.** from the **perspective** of someone else.

Here, I need to look into the ways someone else can think and the relevant attitudes or beliefs about what was mentioned within the previous sentence. 
 In other words, I am going to talk about a other people's thoughts using the word "perspective" and the phrase "point of view". However, I have no idea which collocation sounds more idiomatic here.

To me, they all sound quite correct, both grammatically and semantically and that seems to be only the matter of preference and style. Nevertheless, I think "a" and "d" are more elegant.
I cannot think of any other nuance here.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the choices listed above.

PS. to me, the two options "perspective" and "point of view" more or less mean the same.

Comment: There should be no comma between "think" and "this"

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @gotube. I fixed the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can phrase this.

I would tend to agree with both of your intuitions:

1. All four of your options are grammatically acceptable.
2. (a) and (d) are the better options.

I *might* have a slight preference for (c) over (d). I definitely do prefer (a) instead of either of them.

But there is an even simpler (which usually means "more elegant") phrasing:

> But it might look different **to someone else**.

In the end you can use any of the phrasings without worrying about it too much.

Comment: May I ask you @randomhead whether "**in terms of someone else's perspective**" and "**in terms of someone else's point of view**" are good English structures as in "from someone else's perspective /  point of view"? Of so, then do they mean the same?

Comment: Eh, not really, because it's overly wordy to the point of being redundant. I would stick with "from."